# For certain files in a directory carry out an action

Tags: foreach

I haven't worked with this stuff in years, so please be patient!

I'm having some really weird issues with `Mac Excel` greying out some .csv files but not others. From what I've read so far, this could have something to do with some of the more hidden file parameters.

Anyways, I'd like to find the files with a certain name in the directory, do a getfileinfo on them and spit out the result, i.e. something like:

```
for each i in (ls \*_xyz*.csv) do getfileinfo $i | echo
```

(or whatever more intelligent way this can be accomplished these days...)

I tried a few combinations but keep getting "-bash syntax error", so I've decided it's time to get help...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Create dummy test files:

```
$ touch file{1..10}_xyz.csv

$ ls
file10_xyz.csv  file1_xyz.csv   file2_xyz.csv   file3_xyz.csv   file4_xyz.csv   file5_xyz.csv   file6_xyz.csv   file7_xyz.csv   file8_xyz.csv   file9_xyz.csv
```

There are many ways to do this. My favorite is method1.

Method 1)

```
$ find . -name "*xyz*.csv" -exec someCommand {} \;
```

Method2)

```
$ for x in $( find . -name "*xyz*.csv") ; do someCommand $x ; done
```

Method3)

```
$find . -name "*xyz*.csv" | xargs someCommand
```